# Android Spinner with POST REQUEST

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, custom-adapter

I'm working on some project in which Im getting data from webservice. Now what I have to do is showing that values in `Spinner`. I have tried but got nothing in the spinner. I have make a custom Adapter for that everything is going fine according to me. But I got nothing in a `spinner`. Can someone please sort out my problem. Thanks in Advance.

**How I tried:**

**MainActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher_selection);

//  teacherNameList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    TeacherNameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    teacherNameList = new ArrayList<TeacherNameClass>();
//  TeacherNameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    new GettingTeacherName().execute();


}

public class GettingTeacherName extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(GETTING_QUIZ_URL);
         HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
       try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    try {
        Serv_Response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        try {
            if(Serv_Response != null)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Serv_Response);
                JSONArray quiz = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_NAME);

                for(int i= 0 ; i < quiz.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject c = quiz.getJSONObject(i);
                    String teacherNames = c.getString(TAG_TEACHERNAME);

//                      HashMap<String, String> hash_teachername = new HashMap<String, String>();
//                      hash_teachername.put(TAG_TEACHERNAME, teacherNames);
//                      
                    TeacherNameClass teacherNameClassObj = new TeacherNameClass();

                    teacherNameClassObj.setTeacherName(teacherNames);
//                      teacherNameList.add(teacherNameClassObj);

                    try {
                        teacherNameList.add(teacherNameClassObj);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


    //  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TeacherSelectionActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        CustomTeacherAdapter adapter = new CustomTeacherAdapter(getApplicationContext(),teacherNameList);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
    //  TeacherNameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        TeacherNameSpinner.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) adapter);
    }

}
```

**file.xml of MainActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- Text Label -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Category:"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
/>

<!-- Spinner Element -->
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/app_name"
/>
```

**CustomAdapterActivity**

```
public class CustomTeacherAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
ArrayList<TeacherNameClass> teacherNameList;
//ArrayList<Quiz> quizList;

public CustomTeacherAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<TeacherNameClass> teacherNameList) 
{
      super();
    mContext = context;
    this.teacherNameList = teacherNameList;
}


public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
{
return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_teachername_spinner, null);



//    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
//    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_teachername_spinner, parent, false);
TextView label=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
label.setText(teacherNameList.get(position).getTeacherName());

return convertView;
}
```

file.xml of CustomAdapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

**What I got in Output**

[image]

Comment: did u loged the response ?

Comment: loged the response? are you talking about logcat?

Comment: i mean see whethere u r getting data in teacherNameList, there may be possiblity that list is empty so the spinner is empty

Comment: I got an array of two elements

Comment: ok , just log the teacherNameList.get(position).getTeacherName() in this line also label.setText(teacherNameList.get(position).getTeacherName());

Comment: i have checked on  TeacherNameSpinner.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) adapter); and got values from adapter.

Comment: Why you have implemented the `getDropDownView` and `getCustomView` methods ? Whats the purpose of it ? I think there is no need of it just `getView` method is enough. And make sure you return the size of your arraylist in your adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `getCount` and `getItem(int pos)` methods in your adapter class as below which returns the size of arraylist and item which is going to be inflated into your spinner as below:

```
    @Override
public int getCount() {

    return teacherNameList .size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return teacherNameList.get(position);
}
```